# How to parse an XML file to a list?

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to parse an XML file to a list with Python. I have looked at some solutions on this site and others and could not make them work for me. I have managed to do it but in a laborious way that seems stupid to me. It seems that there should be an easier way.

I have tried to adapt other peoples code to suit my needs but that is not working as I am not always sure of what I am reading.

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <location name ="location">
        <latitude>54.637348</latitude>
        <latHemi>N</latHemi>
        <longitude>5.829723</longitude>
        <longHemi>W</longHemi>
    </location>
    <microphone name="microphone">
        <sensitivity>-26.00</sensitivity>
    </microphone>
    <weighting name="weighting">
        <cWeight>68</cWeight>
        <aWeight>2011</aWeight>
    </weighting>
    <optionalLevels name="optionalLevels">
        <L95>95</L95>
        <L90>90</L90>
        <L50>50</L50>
        <L10>10</L10>
        <L05>05</L05>
        <fmax>fmax</fmax>
    </optionalLevels>
    <averagingPeriod name="averagingPeriod">
        <onemin>1</onemin>
        <fivemin>5</fivemin>
        <tenmin>10</tenmin>
        <fifteenmin>15</fifteenmin>
        <thirtymin>30</thirtymin>
    </averagingPeriod>
    <timeWeighting name="timeWeighting">
        <fast>fast</fast>
        <slow>slow</slow>
    </timeWeighting>
    <rebootTime name="rebootTime">
        <midnight>midnight</midnight>
        <sevenAm>7am</sevenAm>
        <sevenPm>7pm</sevenPm>
        <elevenPm>23pm</elevenPm>
    </rebootTime>
    <remoteUpload name="remoteUpload">
        <nointernet>nointernet</nointernet>
        <vodafone>vodafone</vodafone>
    </remoteUpload>
</configuration>
```

And this is the Python program.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


import os
try:
    import cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    try:
        import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
    except ImportError:
        exit_err("Failed to import cElementTree from any known place")

file_name = ('/home/mark/Desktop/Practice/config_settings.xml')
full_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('data', file_name))

dom = ET.parse(full_file)

tree = ET.parse(full_file)
root = tree.getroot()

location_settings = dom.findall('location')
mic_settings = dom.findall('microphone')
weighting = dom.findall('weighting')
olevels = dom.findall('optionalLevels')
avg_period = dom.findall('averagingPeriod')
time_weight = dom.findall('timeWeighting')
reboot = dom.findall('rebootTime')
remote_upload = dom.findall('remoteUpload')

for i in location_settings:

    latitude = i.find('latitude').text
    latHemi = i.find('latHemi').text
    longitude = i.find('longitude').text
    longHemi = i.find('longHemi').text


for i in mic_settings:
    sensitivity = i.find('sensitivity').text

for i in weighting:
    cWeight = i.find('cWeight').text
    aWeight = i.find('aWeight').text

for i in olevels:
    L95 = i.find('L95').text
    L90 = i.find('L90').text
    L50 = i.find('L50').text
    L10 = i.find('L10').text
    L05 = i.find('L05').text

for i in avg_period:
    onemin = i.find('onemin').text
    fivemin = i.find('fivemin').text
    tenmin = i.find('tenmin').text
    fifteenmin = i.find('fifteenmin').text
    thirtymin = i.find('thirtymin').text

for i in time_weight:
    fast = i.find('fast').text
    slow = i.find('slow').text

for i in reboot:
    midnight = i.find('midnight').text
    sevenAm = i.find('sevenAm').text
    sevenPm = i.find('sevenPm').text
    elevenPm= i.find('elevenPm').text

for i in remote_upload:
    nointernet = i.find('nointernet').text
    vodafone = i.find('vodafone').text

config_list = [latitude,latHemi,longitude,longHemi,sensitivity,aWeight,cWeight,
                L95,L90,L50,L10,L05,onemin,fivemin,tenmin,fifteenmin,thirtymin,
                fast,slow,midnight,sevenAm,sevenAm,elevenPm,nointernet,vodafone]
print(config_list)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please describe your expected output that you want to parse from the XML? You may [edit] your questioin to include that

Comment: What sort of list are you expecting? A single flat list of the toplevel elements? A list of lists?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're posing isn't very well defined.  The XML structure doesn't conform very well to a list structure to begin with.  If you're new to python, I think the best way to go about what you're trying to do is to use something like [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) which will parse the implicit schema in your xml to python data structures.

e.g.

```
import xmltodict
xml = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <location name ="location">
        <latitude>54.637348</latitude>
        <latHemi>N</latHemi>
        <longitude>5.829723</longitude>
        <longHemi>W</longHemi>
    </location>
    <microphone name="microphone">
        <sensitivity>-26.00</sensitivity>
    </microphone>
    <weighting name="weighting">
        <cWeight>68</cWeight>
        <aWeight>2011</aWeight>
    </weighting>
    <optionalLevels name="optionalLevels">
        <L95>95</L95>
        <L90>90</L90>
        <L50>50</L50>
        <L10>10</L10>
        <L05>05</L05>
        <fmax>fmax</fmax>
    </optionalLevels>
    <averagingPeriod name="averagingPeriod">
        <onemin>1</onemin>
        <fivemin>5</fivemin>
        <tenmin>10</tenmin>
        <fifteenmin>15</fifteenmin>
        <thirtymin>30</thirtymin>
    </averagingPeriod>
    <timeWeighting name="timeWeighting">
        <fast>fast</fast>
        <slow>slow</slow>
    </timeWeighting>
    <rebootTime name="rebootTime">
        <midnight>midnight</midnight>
        <sevenAm>7am</sevenAm>
        <sevenPm>7pm</sevenPm>
        <elevenPm>23pm</elevenPm>
    </rebootTime>
    <remoteUpload name="remoteUpload">
        <nointernet>nointernet</nointernet>
        <vodafone>vodafone</vodafone>
    </remoteUpload>
</configuration>"""
d = xmltodict.parse(xml)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. Sorry if the question was not well posed. I have found an answer myself. I was looking to parse the XML child elements into a list for later use in another program. I figured it out. Thank you for your patience.